# Structure in Sharepoint -> Customer -> Project -> Subproject

Tags: content-and-structure, information-architecture

We would like to setup our new sharepoint. We are normally working in a structure where we have customer -> Project -> SubProject. We have seen now that it is not possible to get this deep structure. Is this correct? How are you structuring your informations?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it is not possible to get this deep structure"? What is stopping you?

Comment: Same question as @JaapVossers. Such structures are very common. Site columns and lookups are the key to making this work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this codeless.

If i am right, you want deep structure at same list.

I consider you have 3 fields. While you are creating first(customer) field, make it single line or lookup from another list.

Second one is lookup from same list and look it up from first(customer) field.

And third one is same, look it up from second one. finally you can have deep structure. You can also do this via lot lists.

But if you want to do this one to many relation, i have problem about it. Trying to solve one to many efficiently. When i make it,gonna write here.

Answer (score 0):

You can make lookup for Project list from SubProjects list and lookup to Customer list from Project list.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to secure content then use webs and subwebs for structuring content. but keep a lis of subobject with links to subwebs on parent web.